# AngularJS provider function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function provider(name, provider_) {
  assertNotHasOwnProperty(name, 'service');
  if (isFunction(provider_) || isArray(provider_)) {
    provider_ = providerInjector.instantiate(provider_);
  }
  if (!provider_.$get) {
    throw $injectorMinErr('pget', "Provider '{0}' must define $get factory method.", name);
  }
  return providerCache[name + providerSuffix] = provider_;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L655-680

I was actually looking at the `provider` function of injector.js, it seems that all the services[`constant, value, factory, service and provider itself`] is a mere wrapper of the provider.

Can anyone help me in understanding these questions:

1. Why are all these a `wrapper` of `provider`? Let's take i have a `factory/service` named "`Shane`", why would i pass it to a `provider` to create the "`Shane`" Object?
2. Why is there a `provider/service` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factories, services, and others is a just useful wrappers for provider. Provider request so much code to be written:

```
 angular.module('app', []).provider('myProvider', function(/*here you can inject another providers*/) {
     // this function can be called by another providers
     this.config = function() {}; 
     this.$get = function(/*here you can inject services*/) {
          // exprort your service value
          return {};
     };
 });
```

This is how providers work:

1. First of all, providers can interact with each other and by calling methods like in example above.
2. Then all the `$get` methods are being called from all providers. This function accept other services as arguments, so here you can interact with some services.
3. The result of `$get` method is an actual value of your service which can be injected into another services, controllers, etc.

If your service don't need all of this features, you can skip some first steps and start from any further. If you don't need to work with providers, use `factory`. If you even don't need to use services, use `service` (which works as usual js-constructor function) or `value` if your service actually a static value and doesn't require extra preparations.

Look at the [$provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider) documentation to know about exact API of all of these registering functions.

Comment: I got struck up, can you just help me in answering this... i am getting too confused. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446806/what-is-a-service-and-provider-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment48975581_30446806

Comment: This question is too wide to give the answer rather than was already given. Try to ask in another words

Comment: [Service/Factory/Decorator/Provider] these are providers and not services?. Services are ones we create using these providers? right?

Comment: It depends from stage where you inject your entity. Into `.config` or `.provider` providers will be injected. The factory, directive or something else will get services into inject.

Comment: Also, found [this article](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) in angular docs. It has a nice compare table at the bottom